# Prove that if $x,y$ are vectors in some unitary space and satisfy $||x||=||y||$ then $\exists T\in Hom(V,V),T^*=T^{-1}\land T(x)=y$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am stucked at this problem:

---

Let $V$ be some finite dimensional unitary space and let $x,y\in V$ be some vectors such that $||x||=||y||$, Prove that there exist some unitary transformation $T$ such that $T(x)=y$.

(I.e show that $\exists T\in Hom(V,V),T^*=T^{-1}\land T(x)=y$)

---

Clearly the statement is true from an intuitive point of view:

Suppose we are working in a 3D Euclidean vector space called $V$, And suppose that $x,y\in V$ are some vectors in $V$ that satisfy $||x||=||y||$.

Clearly there exist a sequence of rotations that will transform the vector $x$ to the vector $y$ (since $x$ and $y$ are of the same length).

In other words, there exists a sequence of rotation transformations $T_1,...,T_n\in Hom(V,V)$ such that $T_1(T_2(...T_{n-1}(T_n(x))...))= y$, Now since rotation transformation are orthogonal transformations, And since composition of orthogonal transformations gives an orthogonal transformation we get that there exist some orthogonal transformation  $T=T_1\circ T_2 \circ \circ \circ T_n$ such that $T(x)=y$.

But I do not know how to formalize this proof and **why** there exist such transformation sequence.

---

Thanks for any hint/help.

Comment: Hint: the two vectors define a vector plane. Decompose the problem between that plane and its orthogonal complement.

Comment: To elaborate on the above hint, you might imagine a matrix representation of $T$ as being block-diagonal with a $2 \times 2$ block that captures the $x \mapsto y$ behavior, and then the rest of the matrix can be whatever you like to keep it unitary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following statement:

> Every vector with $\| v \|=1$ is part of an orthonormal basis.

This a well known fact, proven by the Gram–Schmidt process to find an orthonormal basis: Just take any basis, which includes $v$, and then use Gram-Schmidt process, starting with $v$.

Now let us use this:

Of course, we can assume $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$. Because of the fact above, we can choose an orthonormal basis $x=x_1,x_2, \dotsc, x_n$ and an orthonormal basis $y=y_1,y_2, \dotsc, y_n$.

Now, just define $T: x_i \mapsto y_i$. $T$ is unitary since it maps an orthonormal basis to another orthonormal basis, so we are done.

---

We can summarize the following: The fact, that any two vectors of the same length can be mapped to each other by some unitary transformation (Or shortly: $U(n)$ acts transitively on $S^{n-1}$) is the coordinate-free version of the statement above.